# set initialTags for tag-editor jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tageditor

I have used following jquery for my project.

[tag editor](https://goodies.pixabay.com/jquery/tag-editor/demo.html)

I want to set initialTags parameter of tagEditor() from attribute of textarea..

For example:

```
<textarea id="demo3" data-json=""></textarea>

$('#demo3').tagEditor({
initialTags: $(this).attr("data-json"),
placeholder: 'Enter tags ...'
});
```

But here it doesn't work.. Can anyone help me with this???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` in this context isn't the matched element. What you can do is to use a cached variable:

```
var $demo3 = $('#demo3');
$demo3.tagEditor({
  initialTags: $demo3.data("json"),
  placeholder: 'Enter tags ...'
});
```

But don't forget than `initialTags` must be an array.

Comment: check fiddle here, https://jsfiddle.net/hasmukhmistry/a0nyw2oy/

Bit problematic now.. any help??

Comment: Can you update jsFiddle to handle your case. Actaully the link you posted doesn't have any js script nor any data-json. I guess, your issue is because you need to pass an array, not string. E.g: https://fiddle.jshell.net/ofqh0jfa/1/

Answer (score 0):

try this!

```
$('#demo3').tagEditor({ 
    initialTags: ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']
});
```

You should take the input data from array. You are taking the data from an attribute of textarea which is empty.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/hasmukhmistry/a0nyw2oy/ - fiddle updated ,

```
<textarea id="demo3" data-json="some, tags" class="tag-editor-hidden-src" readonly="readonly" style="display: block;"></textarea>
var $demo3 = $('#demo3');
$demo3.tagEditor({
  initialTags: $demo3.data("json").split(','),
  placeholder: 'Enter tags ...'
});
```

Thanks @A. Wolff -[Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1414562/a-wolff)